# Close and update Program Files in Python

Tags: python, python-multithreading

So I've tried Googling my problem and looking on SO here, but I can't seem to find anything.  Maybe I just really suck at using searches.  But anyway here it what I am trying to do.

I have a program written in Python and I am trying to implement a very basic "Update Client" inside of it.  The way this "Update Client" is suppose to work, is when the user chooses to update, the main program is closed and all of the files of the program are modified.

The only thing I am trying to figure out right now, is it is possible to close the main thread of a Python Program, using a thread that starts from that main thread?  Or should I be structuring my code towards my main program starting a completely separate application when the "Update Client" is meant to be opened?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You will need to close the entire process, not just the main thread. You could use a separate program that does the update and restarts the main program.

Comment: @Blorgbeard That's essentially what I want to do yes.  Thanks for clarifying it's the whole process I'll need to shut down.